# PDF.JS mozilla project - preload all pages?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, pdf.js

I've modified the web/viewer from the mozilla PDF.JS project so that I can export pages to separate HTML pages. But when I try to export all pages I notice that the rendering hasn't completed yet.

I've created my own function in viewer.js:

```
renderAll: function pdfViewAll() {
  if (PDFView.idleTimeout) {
    clearTimeout(PDFView.idleTimeout);
    PDFView.idleTimeout = null;
  }

  // Pages have a higher priority than thumbnails, so check them first.
  var allPages = this.getAllPages();
  for (var count = 0; count < this.pages.length; count++) {
      this.renderView(this.pages[count], 'page');
      this.pages[count].scrollIntoView();
  }
},
```

I'm listening on two location to find out if any pages have finished rendering.
First location is when `renderView` is called:

```
renderView: function pdfViewRender(view, type) {
  var state = view.renderingState;
  switch (state) {
    case RenderingStates.FINISHED:
      if (EXPORTING) {
        view.scrollIntoView();
        preparePageExport(view.id);
      }
      return false;
    case RenderingStates.PAUSED:
      PDFView.highestPriorityPage = type + view.id;
      view.resume();
      break;
    case RenderingStates.RUNNING:
      PDFView.highestPriorityPage = type + view.id;
      break;
    case RenderingStates.INITIAL:
      PDFView.highestPriorityPage = type + view.id;
      if (EXPORTING)
          view.scrollIntoView();
      view.draw(this.renderHighestPriority.bind(this));
      break;
  }
  return true;
},
```

Second location is when the callback for the `renderTask` is called:
var renderTask = this.renderTask = this.pdfPage.render(renderContext);

```
this.renderTask.promise.then(
  function pdfPageRenderCallback() {
    pageViewDrawCallback(null);
    if (EXPORTING) {
      preparePageExport(self.id);
    }
  },
  function pdfPageRenderError(error) {
    pageViewDrawCallback(error);
  }
);
```

The preparePageExport(self.id) function is just a function that get the image from the canvas page.
Not all pages are being prepared. I'm still relatively new to PDF.JS so can you see what I'm missing here?

Comment: Printing functionality is doing almost the same, check how it is done there.

Comment: See https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/pull/3670 for the explanation of the logic behind the printing functionality.

Comment: I think I'm not making myself clear, sorry. I don't want to print all the pages, just render them. The default behaviour of the viewer renders pages as they scroll by, but I want to render them all at initial runtime.